# Yet another instance of CSS media queries OK on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css, opera, media-queries

I'm entirely new to the world of CSS, let alone media queries, so any help would be super appreciated!

I'm working on an assignment for school where we have to test our media queries and have a different style sheet for a variety of device sizes. I think I'm basically having the same problem as discussed on this post: [Media Queries - Mobile vs Desktop Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029905/media-queries-mobile-vs-desktop-browser), but it's not clear to me how that commenter resolved their problem.

This is probably the relevant coding where the error lies, I think?:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--container div tag-->

<!-- Low res -->
<link href="colors2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 128px)" />
<!-- Mid res -->
<link href="colors3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 176px)" />
<!-- High res -->
<link href="colors4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 240px)" />
<!-- Touch -->
<link href="colors5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px)" />
```

The queries work on desktop browsers, but when I launch the page on Opera Mobile Emulator with (what I think are) the correct screen resolutions, they all take the default of the min-width 320px style. I've tried to add ", screen and (min-device-width:" to the tags as well, but for some reason, having both cancels the whole thing out and I end up with my basic HTML on a white screen. I've also tried doing the @media thing where I then post the styles below, but it seems like Dreamweaver 6 is rejecting them (???) because they get highlighted in maroon and, again, I get the white background.

So...I'd be very, very thankful for any help! And I should also mention that the very small min-widths are part of the assignment. I think they're all too small, personally! Thanks so much:)

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mobile Emulator works very different from the real app.
I'd suggest you to test the site live in a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks! I'm meeting some people for dinner tonight and I'm hoping they have phones that are a variety of resolutions. The reason I want to get it to work in Emulator is 'cause I'm pretty sure the instructor will be using that to check everyone's work...

Comment: Just a tiny update, I tweaked the coding a little so that it has both min-width and max-width where I think it makes sense, and I've also included "handheld" as a media type in addition to "screen". Still no good! The live preview on Dreamweaver and the actual resizing on the desktop browser work fine, but it's just Opera Emulator. I guess if anyone could tell me for a fact that this type of thing doesn't always render correctly in Emulator?...But I kind of assumed it was meant to handle things like this.

Comment: Anyway, here is the new code, if anyone can shed a light on it! It's an example of just two of them, since there is a character limit.<P>
    <link href="colors2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 128px), handheld and (max-width: 128px)" />
    <!-- Mid res -->
    <link href="colors3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 129px) and (max-width: 176px), handheld and (min-width:129px) and (max-width: 176px)" />