# Media queries work on device but not on browser resize

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I seem to have opposite problem to many other people when it comes to using media queries:
I cannot seem to make the different queries kick in when I'm resizing the browser. But when I access the webpage on my iphone it works fine.

http://dknytkom.dk/forside/

I tested it by adding a background-color to my main container but the color change only occurs on the actual iPhone - not the browser itself.
For instance I've written:

At the top of my grid2.ccs I've set the bg-color of the main container to blue. Further down I write:

```
@media only screen (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1254px) {
      body, #main-container { background-color:pink;}
}
```

and further down again:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {body, #main-container { background-color:yellow;}
```

The color change does occur – but only my device (iPhone) and not on browser resize.

NOTE: Perhaps this thread is on to something:
 [Media Queries - Mobile vs Desktop Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029905/media-queries-mobile-vs-desktop-browser?rq=1)

"If I use max-device-width instead of max-width it becomes responsive on mobile browsers, but not desktop browsers..."

Comment: P.S. Part of the media queries works fine, but I want my columns to expand to 100% when the browser is resized to less than 930px

Comment: Please be more specific as to what code you have used and where – nobody here wants to go through your whole CSS files to find the right spot.

Comment: @CBroe Does my explanation make sense?

Comment: I don’t find `background-color:pink` anywhere in that stylesheet … But first of all, you will have to fix the [error on line 33](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdknytkom.dk%2Fcss%2Fgrid2.css&profile=css3)

Comment: Tried to clean up the file: removed all comments and added semicolons where needed. When I ran the validation again one massive error: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdknytkom.dk%2Fcss%2Fgrid2.css+&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en#errors

Comment: Also tried to remove the main stylesheets to see if it affected/overrules the stylings of grid2.css - but no such luck

Answer (score 4):

And yes - as it turns out the reason for the changes not occurring in the browser was that I specified the css for **min-device-width** and **max-device-width**.

Using just **min-width** and **max-width** did not the trick