# Responsive grid - Verically/Horizontally stacked with changing width/height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive grid that fits the size of a mobile in both landscape and potrait mode.

So I have following components in my div/grid:

1. An Image
2. A Div Talking about its description.
3. A Buy button.
4. A share button.

So in potrait mode all of them have a same width and are stacked vertically, whereas in landscape mode all of them have a height and are stacked horizontally. Eg:

**In Landscape**

[image: Landscape Mode]

**In Potrait**

[image: Potrait Mode]

I am not well versed with css, and have been trying to do this for past two days. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You have to use media queries for responsive design.

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029905/media-queries-mobile-vs-desktop-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a media-query to check for the orientation of a device:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation

You can use this to apply CSS-rules to your elements only if the device is in portrait mode:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { 
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Something like this